# How to replace substrings in strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, and a list of strings that I want to remove from a column in that dataframe.  But when I use the replace function those characters remain.  Can someone please explain why this is the case?

```
bad_chars = ['?', '!', ',', ';', "'", '|', '-', '--', '(', ')', 
             '[', ']', '{', '}', ':', '&', '\n']
```

and to replace:

```
df2['page'] = df2['page'].replace(bad_chars, '')
```

when i print out `df2`:

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    print( row['project'] + '\t' + '(' + row['page'] + ',' + str(row['viewCount']) + ')' + '\n'  )
```

en      (The_Voice_(U.S._season_14),613)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to escape your characters using `re`, then use `pd.Series.str.replace`.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

bad_chars = ['?', '!', ',', ';', "'", '|', '-', '--', '(', ')', 
             '[', ']', '{', '}', ':', '&', '\n']

df = pd.DataFrame({'page': ['hello?', 'problems|here', 'nothingwronghere', 'nobrackets[]']})

df['page'] = df['page'].str.replace('|'.join([re.escape(s) for s in bad_chars]), '')

print(df)

#                page
# 0             hello
# 1      problemshere
# 2  nothingwronghere
# 3        nobrackets
```

Comment: Thank you ver much jpp, that does it perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Use `.str.replace`, and pass your strings as a single, pipeline-separated string. You can use `re.escape()` in order to escape regex characters from that string, as suggested by @jpp. I tweak his suggestion a bit by avoiding iteration:

```
import re 
df2['page'] = df2['page'].str.replace(re.escape('|'.join(bad_chars)), '')
```

Comment: Cheers mcard, when I do that, I get the error :  TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'   If I replace the list variable with a literal example of an element in that list it works though.  Is there a way to replace more than one string at the same time?

Comment: This does not work in the general case, e.g. what about regex characters such as `|` in your bad character list?

Comment: THey need to be escaped with a ´\´

Comment: So is the only way to manually go through the list of bad characters one by one to check for escapes? I'm sure there's a better way...

Comment: Thanks folks for talking a look, I'm accepting jpp's answer as it does exactly what I'm looking for in a generic way.

Comment: We both improved upon each other's previous answers. I believe my code line shows the best way to do it.

Comment: apologies, I ran run the same code twice, but when I run mcard's updated version, while no error is thrown, the data stays the same - maybe an iteration is needed for some reason. (at least with my dataset)